# How to fix wrong Math calculation?

Tags: java, android

I've tried to make very simple calculator with only "int" values. The problem is: whatever numbers are calculated - the answer is "0". What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it? (Here is my code with addition for example)

```
    private EditText input;
    private EditText input2;
    private TextView result;
    private Button plus;

    private String inputStr;
    private String input2Str;

    private int inp1;
    private int inp2;
    private int rslt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = findViewById(R.id.input);
        input2 = findViewById(R.id.input2);
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        plus = findViewById(R.id.plus_btn);

       input.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            inputStr = input.getText().toString();
            inp1 = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        });
        input2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            input2Str = input2.getText().toString();
            inp2 = Integer.parseInt(input2Str);
        });


        rslt = 0;
        plus.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            rslt = inp1 + inp2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(rslt));
        });
```

Comment: set a breakpoint here `rslt = inp1 + inp2;` and debug your code to see the actual values

Comment: you need variable operation_type, on plus click store operator type, on result click parse numbers and do an operation by switch case

Comment: Those `OnClickListener`s you've set on your `EditText`s are likely not working as you think. Get rid of those, and move the `inputStr`/`inp1` and `input2Str`/`inp2` lines all into `plus`'s `OnClickListener`, first thing.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you, that's helped a lot

Comment: No problem. That was just a quick suggestion for the example snippet you posted here, btw, to hopefully illustrate what was happening there. You'll likely want to organize your code differently, so you don't have to copy them into every operator button's `OnClickListener`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    plus.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //put rslt = 0; below...
        rslt = 0;
        rslt = inp1 + inp2;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(rslt));
    });
```